# I implemented Firebase push notification in my react-native android app, but notifications are not receiving on the app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented Firebase push notification in my react-native android app, I can see Notifications in send section in firebase console, but notifications are not receiving on the app, neither when the app in in foreground nor in the background.

- I have installed react-native-firebase/app ,react-native-firebase/messaging, react-native-firebase/messaging, react-native-push-notification.
- Connected firebase to react-native app project (downloading json file)
- Added the following dependency in android-Build.Gradle `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'`
- Added the following dependency and plugin in android/app-Build.Gradle Plugin`implementation project(':react-native-push-notification') implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')`
  plugin `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
- The App run but it did not show any notification.

Below is my App.js file code

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PushController from './src/PushController';

import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text, StatusBar, FlatList} from 'react-native';

import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);

import {Header, LearnMoreLinks, Colors, DebugInstructions, ReloadInstructions } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';


const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <View>
        <Text>Zoha</Text>
      </View>
      <PushController/>
    </Fragment>
  );
};


export default App;
```

Below is  PushController.js file code and i imported it in App.js file

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);

// var PushNotification = require("react-native-push-notification");

export default class PushController extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
      messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
  console.log( 'Notification caused app to open from background state:', remoteMessage, );
});

// Check whether an initial notification is available
messaging().getInitialNotification().then(remoteMessage => {
    console.log( 'Notification caused app to open from quit state:', remoteMessage, );
});
        PushNotification.configure({
            // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
            onRegister: function(token) {
              console.log("TOKEN:", token);
            },
          
            // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
            onNotification: function(notification) {
              console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
          
              // process the notification here
            },
            // Android only
            senderID: "*******",
            
            popInitialNotification: true,
            requestPermissions: true
          });
    }

    render(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

and Manifest.xml file code is below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      

      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
                  android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>
  <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
              android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
  <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
              android:resource="@android:color/white"/>

  <receiver
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

  <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
  <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver"
  android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
  <service
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
      android:exported="false" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.